# Map View getting Location

Tags: android

I'm using a Map View and I'm able to get the current location. but now my problem is I want to put a marker on the specific place that near me. for an example I want to put a marker to all the Starbucks that near to my current location. I don't have any idea how to do this. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are innumerable examples of using Map Overlays on Android.  Here is one of them.  Just take the locations you have and do put them in this code:

[Map Overlay Example](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/11/display-marker-on-mapview-using.html)

If you are asking how to get the locations of the things you want to put on the map, then you are going to need to use something like the Google Places API with documentation found here:

[Google Place API Docs](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

Comment: To help make sure you get answers in the future, be sure to click accept jf this answered your question.